# How to mix ARM64 and X64 versions of dotnet core on my MacBook M1

Tags: .net-core, version, apple-m1

I have a new Macbook Pro (M1) and I need to install multiple versions of dotnet core - my large solution has a mixture of versions, to busy to address that issue right now.

But how to I handle this situation ?  (note I have a symlink for the X64 version of dotnet)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it will work for your specific case, but if you're okay with x64 architecture for all .NET versions, it should work.

- Delete `usr/local/share/dotnet` if you have one.
- Download installers with x64 architecture for all .NET versions you need;
- You need to figure out which of them will be placed in 64 folder. !! Install them first !! After this inside `usr/local/share/dotnet` you will have only `64` folder.
- Copy all files from `usr/local/share/dotnet/64` to `usr/local/share/dotnet`
- Delete `usr/local/share/dotnet/64` folder
- Install the rest of versions via installer and be sure that thay will be placed in `usr/local/share/dotnet` NOT in `usr/local/share/dotnet/64`